# laravel file upload with ajax request (base64 concept)

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, image-upload

can anyone help me to find out some demo or script for file upload in Laravel 5 with AJAX REQUEST? i have done on simple submit page i need to have code or demo of ajax request file upload only. and using base64 concept will be more helpful. Thanks in advance folks.

Comment: why use base64? this is more for uploading from mobile os like ios, android

Comment: no but in laravel view page i want to show image in thumb near to upload button before it get actually uploaded so i need to encode the image append in myajax call data.

Comment: You can't do this, because you only can get image filename, you can't even get file path and even less image content.

Comment: you can encode on server side when user submit the file. and save it to the database / move it to folder

Comment: friends here is the link visit what i was looking for now i just need to change code core php to laravel framework.                                                                       http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/uploading-files-with-ajax--net-21077

Comment: you don't need base64 for this.

Answer (score 0):

Encode this image to base64 in controller file. I am not write this code

//Controller File

```
use File;
use Response;
class JsUpload extends Controller {
public function store(Request $request){
    $data = array();
    if($request->hasFile('image_file')){
        $file = Input::file('image_file');
        $name = time().'_'.$file->getClientOriginalName();
        $file = $file->move(public_path().'/images/',$name);

        //store $name into database;

        return Response::json([
            'success' => true,
        ]); 

    }
    else{
        return Response::json([
            'success' => false,
        ]); 
    }
}}
```

//Route File

```
Route::post('uploadviajs','JsUpload@store');
```

//HTML FORM

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file"  name="image_file" id="image_file" >
<button id="imageupload">Upload</button>
</form>
```

//Script File

```
<script>
$('#imageupload').click(function(e) {
var myFormData = new FormData();
myFormData.append('image_file', image_file.files[0]);
$.ajax({
    url: "{!! url('artistProfileImage') !!}",
    type: 'POST',
    data: myFormData,
    cache: false,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    beforeSend: function() {    
    },  
    complete: function() {  
    },              
    success: function(json) {       
    },
    error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert(thrownError + "\r\n" + xhr.statusText + "\r\n" + xhr.responseText);
    }
}); });</script>
```

Comment: So what if I uploaded a PHP script and visited http:// my-insecure-laravel-upload.com/images/[timestamp]_super_evil.php?